# can't redirect_to current_user in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm newbie in ruby on rails, and i trying to update my user, but when my user updated, i can't redirect_to my current_user. This is my controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = (current_user.blank? ? User.all : User.find(:all, :conditions => ["id != ?", current_user.id]))
  end

  def create
    user = User.login(params[:session][:username], params[:session][:pass])
    if user
      login user
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      redirect_to welcome_index_path
    end
  end

  def sucess
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @relation = Relation.new
  end

  def edit
    if current_user.update_attributes(:image => params[:image])
      logger.debug "image: #{current_user.image}"
      if current_user.changed?
        redirect_to current_user
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    else
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logout
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

my routes

```
  get "uploads/new"

  get "micropost/new"

  get "user/new"
  get "user/saved"

  get "post/new"
  get "post/show"

  get "welcome/index"
  get "welcome/sucess"
  get "welcome/edit"
  get "welcome/test"
  root :to => "welcome#index"
  get '/users/:id', :to => 'welcome#sucess', :as => "user"  

  match '/relations', to: 'relation#create', via: 'post'
  match '/relations/:id', to: 'relation#destroy', via: 'delete'
  resources :users
  resources :relations,  only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts
  resources :uploads


  match '/welcome/edit', to: 'welcome#edit', via: 'post'
  match '/login', to: 'welcome#create', via: 'post'
  match '/logout' => 'welcome#destroy', as: :logout
  match '/create', to: 'micropost#create', via: 'post'
  match '/signup', to: 'user#signup', via: 'post'
```

When i check log file:

```
  Started POST "/welcome/edit?method=post" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-13 15:09:00 +0700
Processing by WelcomeController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XHQeEBjnndipJ8c4TrOnn5Yzh7xqvcEhl4+L7BbGBY0=", "image"=>"Hydrangeas.jpg", "commit"=>"Save", "method"=>"post"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'sa1234' AND "users"."id" != 10) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "image" = 'Hydrangeas.jpg', "updated_at" = '2014-11-13 08:09:00.576402' WHERE "users"."id" = 10[0m
  [1m[35m (157.0ms)[0m  commit transaction
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 10]]
image: Hydrangeas.jpg
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 10]]
  Rendered welcome/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
Completed 200 OK in 219.0ms (Views: 52.0ms | ActiveRecord: 159.0ms)
```

I don't know how my app render edit without my current_user update sucessfull, please! help me to fix that :)

Update:
@Jakob S, this is my log when i try your code:

```
Started GET "/welcome/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-13 15:21:57 +0700
Processing by WelcomeController#edit as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mUser Exists (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'sa1234' AND "users"."id" != 10) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  commit transaction
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 10]]
image: 
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/10
Completed 302 Found in 5.0ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)


Started GET "/users/10" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-13 15:21:57 +0700
Processing by WelcomeController#sucess as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"10"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "10"]]
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relations" ON "users"."id" = "relations"."following_id" WHERE "relations"."follower_id" = 10
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relations" ON "users"."id" = "relations"."follower_id" WHERE "relations"."following_id" = 10[0m
  Rendered welcome/sucess.html.erb within layouts/application (7.0ms)
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 10]]
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
Completed 200 OK in 39.0ms (Views: 37.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Please. post whole code of your controller and routes.rb.

Comment: I edited my question, please see it

Comment: Please post the full log from the relevant action. There must be relevant output above the `image: Desert.jpg` line.

Comment: I posted my log file, please see it

Answer (score 0):

The `current_user.changed?` is causing your problems.

`changed?` is part of Rails' [Dirty model checking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html). A models dirty states (ie which attributes were changed) is reset when the model is saved.

`update_attributes` [updates all attributes and saves the object](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes). Thus `current_user.changed?` will always be `false` right after `update_attributes`, because the model hasn't been changed since the last save.

Remove the check for `changed?` and its related `render "edit"` part, and you should be good to go:

```
def edit
  if current_user.update_attributes(:image => params[:image])
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Bonus tip: Generally speaking an action like the one you're implementing, where you update a resource, would usually go in the `update` action. The `edit` action is usually used for rendering the UI for changing a resource.

Comment: I can't even go to my edit page. I posted my log with your code, please see it!

Comment: A cursory glance at the log shows that you can indeed go to the edit page, and that it actually redirects to the current user. So as far as I can tell, everything works. If you have further problems and questions, feel free to post another question with just the details necessary to reproduce this new problem. I'll be happy to try and answer there, but it'll get too messy doing it in this question.